# Error when trying to convert html to pdf using DomPDF

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I'm using the `Barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` which is a laravel 5 wrapper for the domPDF library ([Link to GIT](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)). But after I ran a `composer update` on my project, I get a error message when I try to convert a html file to a pdf file. The error is as follow `FatalErrorException in class.pdf.php line 1876: Call to undefined method Cpdf::o_rapport()`. I couldn't find a solution for the specific problem so I tried to downgrade the version of the `Barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`and run composer again, but that didn't help. So after that I looked at the stacktrace and tried finding the piece of code that fires the FatalError, but nowhere in the code the method o_rapport() is being called, even if I use the search function of my IDE to search my complete project for this method, no reference are found so that is a dead end aswell.

Now I want to ask if someone did encounter the same problem as me and how to fix this.

Comment: Looks like you not install cpdf. You can try fpdf, for me works fine.

Comment: The dompdf library does have a file `cpdf.adapter.cls.php` file which I guess includes all the logic that cpdf needs?